# get Object inside array javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am struggling to get json object outside `XMLHttpRequest`.This is what I did:

```
    var ohl_json=[];
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.responseType = 'json';
    req.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json', true);
    req.onload  = function() {
      var jsonResponse = req.response;
      ohl_json.push(jsonResponse)
    };
    req.send();
    console.log(ohl_json)
```

I get following output:

```
Array []
​
0: Object { type: "FeatureCollection", features: (960) […] }
​​
features: Array(960) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
type: "FeatureCollection"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I tried to reference it with `ohl_json[0]` or `ohl_json.features` but no success. How can I access it?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, you have set the 3rd parameter of `req.open` as `true` which means it will work asynchronously.

```
req.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json', true);
```

If you wrap your XMLHttpRequest into a promise and resolve with the response then you would be able to get the JSON outside the function.

```js
function getResponse() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.responseType = 'json';
     req.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json', true); // Third parameter is true which means request will work asyncronously.
   
     req.onload  = function() { 
       resolve(req.response);
     };
     
     req.send();
   });
}

getResponse()
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res.features);
});
```

Comment: Very clean and promising. But, how can I use res.features outside getResponse() function? I want to save it to global variable.

Comment: To use your global variable, you have to make sure your request has completed which is an async call. So your global var is dependent on this call. Can you explain a bit how do you use this variable?

Comment: Sure. Variable ohl_json is to be used later in code to generate Leaflet layer and show it on map.

Comment: If you want to use this feature as a global variable, I would suggest to use a state manager (Redux, Mobx, etc).  Because this call is asynchronous and if you want to put it in a global variable then you have to wait till the response completed. So one option to call the `getResponse` where you want to use this value or another option to use a state manager.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this:

```
async function getData(){
  const data =  await (await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json')).json()

  console.log(data.features)
};

getData();
```

Doing this, you will acess the features object =)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. I get  Uncaught TypeError: can't access property 0, ohl_json[0] is undefined

Comment: Try this:

let ohl_json = [];
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json', true);
    req.addEventListener('load', function(test){
      ohl_json.push(req.responseText)
    })
    req.send();

    console.log(ohl_json)

Comment: It gets data, as array of text. i.e: "Array [ "{\n  \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n  \"features\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"Feature\" ". How can I parse this back to json format?

Comment: you can use JSON.parse() function - like this:

let ohl_json = []; 
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/testSO.json', true); 
req.addEventListener('load', function () { 
      ohl_json.push(JSON.parse((req.responseText)))
}) 
req.send();

Comment: OK It works, but I again get an array with objects: Array []
​
0: Object { type: "FeatureCollection", features: (960) […] }
​
1: 1
​
length: 2

Comment: Now you can iterate through this object using some loop logic.
For example, to acess "features" object, you can put this code after "ohl_json.push":

ohl_json.forEach(item => console.log(item.features))